# Nginx How to apply headers to a specific file without breaking the other rules

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have an nginx setup with several folders with  aliases

```
        location /some-path {
            alias ../../path/to/folder1/www;
        }
        location /some-path-2 {
            alias ../../path/to/folder2/www;
        }
```

Every folder has one specific file that I'd like to be served with a header.

But when I try to add a rule for that file, the other rules stop working. This part I took from several answers here on stackoverflow:

```
        location ~* .*file.name$ {
            add_header 'Header' 'value';
        }
```

Then requesting `/some-path/file.name` and `/some-path-2/file.name` results  in 404

How should I configure nginx to add these header rules and then fall back to the other rules?

Answer (score 3):

There are several variants of how to solve this issue. But each of them related to copy-paste a part of the configuration.

### First variant

You may define separate location for each path

```
location ~ /some-path/file.name {
    alias ../../path/to/folder1/www;
    add_header 'Header' 'value';
}

location ~ /some-path-2/file.name {
    alias ../../path/to/folder2/www;
    add_header 'Header' 'value';
}
```

It would work because locations with regular expressions would be processed first.

### Second variant

You may use nested locations

```
location /some-path {
    alias ../../path/to/folder1/www;
    location ~ file.name$ {
        add_header 'Header' 'value';
    }
}
location /some-path-2 {
    alias ../../path/to/folder2/www;
    location ~ file.name$ {
        add_header 'Header' 'value';
    }
}
```

### Third variant

```
map $uri $path_alias {
    default "";
    ~/some-path "../../path/to/folder1/www";
    ~/some-path-2 "../../path/to/folder2/www";
}
server {
    location ~ ^some-path {
        alias  $path_alias;
        location ~ file.name$ {
            add_header 'Header' 'value';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that there's no generic way to do this? Ok, don't mind actually.

Comment: In this case, generic way makes configuration much more difficult. Added example to answer

Comment: Yeah, understood. In my real scenario, it's not just some path, but completely different paths, hard to be matched with one pattern. Thank you!